# Can I Rollback a restore ? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, restore, rollback

Is there anyway to rollback a restore which performed by mistake?

(using a different databases' backup file) SQL Server

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup that was taken before you did the restore yes, but a restore is not something that can be just rolled back if you don't have backups to re-create from.

Comment: there is no backup taken before. assume that i take backup from a db with name test with database files test.mdf and test.ldf what happens when i restore this backup on test2 database?will test2 databases' database files removed and replaced with test.mdf and test.ldf or they will remain and test2 databases' database files will changed as test.mdf and test.ldf. Am i clear?  If  test2.mdf and test2.ldf are remained that is the solution right?

Comment: how to undo accidentally restored sql server db.